# Is it possible to be notified when W3C specs get updated?

Tags: notifications, w3c, specifications

WHATWG [has announced](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-November/033946.html) recently that it's possible now to get notified about the changes in some sections of specifications (more on the way). Is there a similar mechanism for W3C specs? Is it possible to get notified of updates by email or through a feed?

Answer (score 2):

If the specs are posted online (and I have to assume that w3c specs are), then why not use a service like http://www.changedetection.com/ ?

There are several similar services which will notify you whenever any web page is changed and you can even limit the checking ot certain parts of the page (to avoid changing banner headlines, for instance).

hope this helps

Comment: This seemed great while it lasted... :( But today I got the email from changedetection.com:

At your request we have been trying to monitor the following page
for changes:

http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/

Unfortunately, we have been unable to successfully access that page for the
past few weeks. This is usually due to the webmaster moving the page or
closing their site.

The most recent error we received when trying to access this page was:

Blocked by robots.txt

Because of this you have been unsubscribed from monitoring that page.

Comment: So... this doesn't seem to be a reliable way to get updates from the pages like this after all.

Comment: hmmm, I just loaded that page. Wonder why their service has problems? I doubt if it's in robots.txt as the W3C would probably want that googled.  Perhaps try another such service? (there are several)  I have used this method on several occasions and always been satisfied.

Comment: Or, you could look for a newsletter and subscribe. If none, then ask the webmaster to set one up.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the W3C specs are managed by version controlling systems like Git or Mercurial. Apart from being able to actually clone the repository and regularly pull in the changes, one can simply subscribe to the updates in RSS or Atom format. Every spec has it's own channel, but [here's the page](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/) that seemingly lists them all, along with corresponding links - to repositories, zip/tarballs or RSS/Atom channels.

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/

While this is definitely great. Some of the specifications are still off the list like [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).